# How can I programmatically connect to multiple K8S clusters created with the eksctl command in AWS EKS?

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-cluster, k8s-serviceaccount

I want to push some jobs.yml script to multiple Kubernetes clusters programmatically, connection details will be provided by customers and we can store it in encrypted format in DB or maybe S3.

I'm trying to achieve this with `@kubernetes/client-node` the npm package. I was checking the official repository and documentation, I can do this by loading my `~/kube/config` file inside `kc.loadFromFile()`, but my k8s was created with aws `eksctl create cluster -f cluster.yaml` command, which autneticated with your `aws configure`.

What kind of credentials i need to ask from my user? and what fields should i take? Because i can see my kubeconfig file have some aws related keys/values and i want to make my solution available to k8s independent not specific to aws cloud. So, what credentials i need to ask?

I tried to use my `/.kube/config` file  `@kubernetes/client-node` in a separate environment where I don't have `aws configure` the setup done. So I simply copied my `/.kube/config` to another EC2 instance for testing inside a nodejs project and I'm getting an error.

index.js

```js
const k8s = require('@kubernetes/client-node');

const kc = new k8s.KubeConfig();
kc.loadFromFile('/.kube/config');
const k8sApi = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.CoreV1Api);

k8sApi.listNamespacedPod('default').then((res) =\> {
let pods = res.body.items;
console.log(pods);
});
```

Error

```
(node:259164) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null     at ExecAuth.getCredential (/home/ubuntu/test/node_modules/@kubernetes/client-node/dist/exec_auth.js:87:39)     at ExecAuth.applyAuthentication (/home/ubuntu/test/node_modules/@kubernetes/client-node/dist/exec_auth.js:23:33)     at KubeConfig.applyAuthorizationHeader (/home/ubuntu/test/node_modules/@kubernetes/client-node/dist/config.js:368:33)     at KubeConfig.applyOptions (/home/ubuntu/test/node_modules/@kubernetes/client-node/dist/config.js:376:20)     at KubeConfig.applyToRequest (/home/ubuntu/test/node_modules/@kubernetes/client-node/dist/config.js:99:20)     at /home/ubuntu/test/node_modules/@kubernetes/client-node/dist/gen/api/coreV1Api.js:9993:95 (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created) (node:259164) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2) (node:259164) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

My ./kube/config looks like this

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: A_LONG_STRING_HERE
    server: https://XXXXXXXXXXXXX.gr7.ap-south-1.eks.amazonaws.com
  name: xxxxxxx.ap-south-1.eksctl.io
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: xxxxxx.ap-south-1.eksctl.io
    user: iam-root-account@xxxxx.ap-south-1.eksctl.io
  name: iam-root-account@xxxxx.ap-south-1.eksctl.io
- context:
    cluster: xxxx.ap-south-1.eksctl.io
    user: user@xxxxx.ap-south-1.eksctl.io
  name: user@xxxxx.ap-south-1.eksctl.io
current-context: iam-root-account@xxxxx.ap-south-1.eksctl.io
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: iam-root-account@xxxxxx.ap-south-1.eksctl.io
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
      args:
      - token
      - -i
      - xxxxxxx
      command: aws-iam-authenticator
      env:
      - name: AWS_STS_REGIONAL_ENDPOINTS
        value: regional
      - name: AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
        value: ap-south-1
      provideClusterInfo: false
- name: <NAME>@xxxxx.ap-south-1.eksctl.io
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
      args:
      - token
      - -i
      - xxxxxxxx
      command: aws-iam-authenticator
      env:
      - name: AWS_STS_REGIONAL_ENDPOINTS
        value: regional
      - name: AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
        value: ap-south-1
      provideClusterInfo: false
```